# Conditioning on Independent Variable

Tags: probability

I want to prove that if $x$ and $y$ are independent, that is $P(x | y) = P(x)$,
then $P(x | y, z) = P(x| z)$. Intuitively this is clear, as $y$ does not provide any information about $x$ because they are independent and introducing $z$ should not affect this.

I am struggling to show this formally. How can I prove this?

Comment: @user597654 I accidentally used someone else's account on the same computer, so I created my own account. I changed the variables because the system wouldn't let me post otherwise. I hope that's alright.

Comment: @Quack no, it's not really allowed. Reposts of questions are only allowed when they add constructive meaning to the dialogue that a previous question didn't. However, since I understand your position, it can slide this time only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Intuitively this is clear, as $Y$ does not provide any information about $X$ because they are independent and introducing $Z$ should not affect this.

Why should it not?   $Z$ *may* be related to $X$ and $Y$ in a way such that *jointly* $Y$ and $Z$ provide information about $X$.   $Z$ may add clues.

Consider for example $Z=X+Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent.   $Y$ alone provides no information about $X$, however it is clear that knowing values for *both* $Y$ and $Z$ fixes the value for $X$.   That is to say, $X$ is not conditionally independent of $Y$ when given $Z$.

Independence of two random variables does *not entail* that they will be conditionally independent when given a third random variable.

> I am struggling to show this formally. How can I prove this?

Because it is not generally true, therefore you cannot prove it.

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you're struggling to show this, since it's false! Here's a counterexample (swap $X, Y, Z$ for $A, B, C$):

[image: Venn diagram example]